# innodb crashed with error number 5 and mysql wont start

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, mysql-error-2002

hello my database stop today and dont start again.

```
2019-12-10 10:08:02 26295 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-12-10 10:08:03 26295 [ERROR] InnoDB: Error in system call pread(). The operating system error number is 5.
2019-12-10 10:08:03 7f21d3356780  InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Error number 5 means 'Input/output error'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2019-12-10 10:08:03 26295 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 105. Cannot continue operation
```

please help me i lost the database data. can start again the mysql and get data or resolve this error? thank you.

Comment: Probably best solution would be to restore your last backup

Comment: Is this on your server or is it hosted elsewhere? This could be a hard drive failure.

Comment: @RobMoll this is in my server

Comment: @RiggsFolly can i restore data from ibd file?

Comment: No, you MUST backup your database daily as this is on a live server RIGHT?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes this is a live server but my backup is old

Comment: Ah, lesson learned I assume

Comment: Really looks like bad sectors on HDD. Try running a disk health utility appropriate for your OS.

Comment: @RobMoll can you avoid application ?

Comment: @Armin I don't understand your question.

Comment: @RobMoll i need a disk health utility i dont know what to do :(

Comment: Which OS are you running? Linux? Windows?

Comment: @RobMoll linux centos